# Flutter: RangeError

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to add task to list folderTask. The list looks like this:

```
List<FolderTask> folderTask = [];
List<Task> task = [];
folderTask = [FolderTask(name: 'Personal', task: task)];
```

And it return RangeError. The method that I use to add the item inside list Task is this:

```
void setTask(int index, newTask) {
    var specificIndex = folderTask
        .indexWhere((element) => element.name == folderTask[index].name);
    if (folderTask.isEmpty) {
      createInitialData();
    } else if (specificIndex != -1) {
      folderTask[index] =
          FolderTask(name: folderTask[index].name, task: newTask);
      // folderTask[index] = newTask;

    }
    updateDatabase();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is on my first page, user be able to add new folder and inside that folder, user be able to add new task. But it return the rangeeror. Is it because of this:

```
int? index = db.folderTask.indexOf(widget.folderTask);
```

or is it because of I use Provider with ChangeNotifier and Consumer makes the rangeerror?

```
class Task {
  String? name;
  String? note;
  String? reminderDate;
  String? repeat;
  String dueDate;
  bool? isChecked = false;
  String? reminderTime;
  List path = [];

  Task(
      {required this.name,
      required this.note,
      required this.dueDate,
      required this.reminderDate,
      required this.repeat,
      required this.path,
      required this.reminderTime,
      this.isChecked});
  factory Task.fromJson(json) {
    return Task(
        name: json['name'],
        note: json['note'],
        dueDate: json['dueDate'],
        reminderDate: json['reminderDate'],
        reminderTime: json['reminderTime'],
        repeat: json['repeat'],
        path: json['path'],
        isChecked: json['isChecked']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "note": note,
        "dueDate": dueDate,
        "reminderDate": reminderDate,
        "reminderTime": reminderTime,
        "repeat": repeat,
        "path": path,
        'isChecked': isChecked
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add task like this

```
  List<FolderTask> folderTask = [];
  List<Task> task = [];
  folderTask.add[task] // this line
```

Comment: It says List<Map> can't be assigned to parameter 'FolderTask' maybe because of my Task model. Let me update the Task model above to show to you

Answer (score 0):

folderTask[index] =
FolderTask(name: folderTask[index].name, task: newTask);

It's seems like you trying to add newTask in your list, try doing it with `folderTask.add(newTask)`.
Couse you havent index-th element in your list and you actualy want to change it. Here is reason.

```
void main() {
  List<int> test = []; 
  test[1] = 1;
}
```

try this in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?) and you will see your mistake. And be carefull with your List types.

Comment: Provider.of<ToDoDatabase>(context, listen: false).setTask(
                      index,
                      Task(
                          name: taskNameController.text,
                          note: notesController.text,
                          dueDate: dateController.text,
                          reminderDate: reminderDateController.text,
                          repeat: valueRepeat,
                          path: pathList,
                          reminderTime: reminderTimeController.text,
                          isChecked: false));

Still same rangerError

Comment: I fixed it previous error. but now it shows this error. type 'Task' is not a subtype of type 'FolderTask'

Comment: what type is your second argument in setTask? (newTask)

Comment: Dont worry its just a type problem. You trying to add Task element into FolderTask, so as i see you want to add your task into FolderTask.task, but actualy in one folder can be more than one tasks, so you need to make FolderTask.task list.

Comment: Hakob its index

Comment: Can you add please definition of FolderTask class?

Comment: And is type of newTask in setTask function  Task?

Comment: How can I make FolderTask.task list? There's no option for toList and plus task is already a list. Could you explain sir thank you :)

Comment: class FolderTask {
  String? name;
  List task;
  FolderTask({required this.name, required this.task});
  factory FolderTask.fromJson(json) {
    return FolderTask(name: json['name'], task: json['task'] ?? ['Hello']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": name, "task": task};
}

This is the FolderTask class and setTask is a function to add task inside folderTask list

Comment: So in your FolderTask class `List task` task is type of List and you change task:[newTask] in your setTask, and add please type of List in FolderTask Class like this List<Task> task.

Comment: After change your setTask like this. 

`void setTask(int index, newTask) {
    var specificIndex = folderTask
        .indexWhere((element) => element.name == folderTask[index].name);
    if (folderTask.isEmpty) {
      createInitialData();
    } else if (specificIndex != -1) {
      folderTask[index] =
          FolderTask(name: folderTask[index].name, task: [newTask]);
      // folderTask[index] = newTask;

    }
    updateDatabase();
    notifyListeners();
  }`

Comment: `folderTask[index] = FolderTask(name: folderTask[index].name, task: [newTask]);`

just change this, and its will be fine

Comment: it throws an error List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<Task> and the error came from here 'FolderTask(
        name: json['name'],
        task: json['task'] ??
            [
              Task(
                  name: 'Default task',
                  note: 'note',
                  dueDate: 'dueDate',
                  reminderDate: 'reminderDate',
                  repeat: 'repeat',
                  path: ['path'],
                  reminderTime: 'reminderTime')
            ]);'

Comment: can you please send edited code?